Tkinter button height changes when compound option reconfigured from none to any other value
I'm trying to add to my application a couple of buttons with an image and text. By default all buttons have hidden text by setting:
compound=tk.NONE
When one specific button is pushed - compound is switched to any other value, for example
compound=tk.LEFT
Then button height change can be observed. I can't understand why. Maybe it is normal behavior or what is more probable - maybe it's my fault and some additional/different setups are needed.
I read that when a button has specified image and text then its size input values are processed as pixels not as a font character size. In my case its true, checked that a font size doesn't impact button height.
I have prepared simple application that present this problem:
import tkinter as tk

class psWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent) -> None:
        self.parent = parent
       
        #Main window geometry
        self.setParentGeometry()

        #Parent grid weight
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        #Frame 1, spread to parent size
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(parent,height=50,
                               width=50,background='black',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.frame1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=tk.NSEW)

        #Frame 1 grid weight
        self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.frame1.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

        #Some button global properties
        self.buttonWidth = 50
        self.fontList1 = ['Calibri', '12']

        #Dummy image, 1x1 pixel
        self.dummyImgB1 = tk.PhotoImage(width=1,height=1)

        #Button 1
        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.frame1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            text='Button height changes', font=self.fontList1, 
                            background='orange', width=self.buttonWidth,
                            height=40, image=self.dummyImgB1, compound=tk.NONE,
                            command=self.unwrapMenu)
        self.b1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=tk.NSEW)

        #Button 2
        self.b2 = tk.Button(self.frame1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        text='No text', font=self.fontList1, 
                        background='lime', width=self.buttonWidth,
                        height=60, image=self.dummyImgB1, compound=tk.NONE)
        self.b2.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=tk.NSEW)      
 
    def setParentGeometry(self) -> None:
        self.parent.geometry('200x100+200+200')
        self.parent.maxsize(200,100)
        self.parent.minsize(200,100)
        self.parent.update()

    def unwrapMenu(self) -> None:

        #Switch command, set nonzero compound value to show text
        self.b1.configure(command=self.wrapMenu,
                          compound=tk.LEFT)

        #Get size of button 1 and print it 
        x = self.b1.winfo_width()
        y = self.b1.winfo_height()
        s = 'Button 1 (wrapped) size: x=' + repr(x) + ', y=' + repr(y)
        print(s)

        #Get size of button 2 and print it 
        x = self.b2.winfo_width()
        y = self.b2.winfo_height()
        s = 'Button 2 (wrapped) size: x=' + repr(x) + ', y=' + repr(y)
        print(s)
    
    def wrapMenu(self) -> None:

        #Switch command, set compound value to none to hide text
        self.b1.configure(command=self.unwrapMenu,
                          compound=tk.NONE)

        #Get size of button 1 and print it 
        x = self.b1.winfo_width()
        y = self.b1.winfo_height()
        s = 'Button 1 (unwrapped) size: x=' + repr(x) + ', y=' + repr(y)
        print(s)

        #Get size of button 2 and print it 
        x = self.b2.winfo_width()
        y = self.b2.winfo_height()
        s = 'Button 2 (unwrapped) size: x=' + repr(x) + ', y=' + repr(y)
        print(s)       

# create main window
window = tk.Tk()
app = psWindow(window)
window.mainloop()

200x100 app window with two buttons, first with 40 pix height, second with 60 pix height. Both have an image (1x1 pixel size) and text (by default hidden). When orange button is clicked then its text is showed and its height changes.
Button text hidden
Button text showed
Printed output:
Button 1 (wrapped) size: x=200, y=40
Button 2 (wrapped) size: x=200, y=60
Button 1 (unwrapped) size: x=200, y=44
Button 2 (unwrapped) size: x=200, y=56

So after text is enabled by setting compound option to tk.LEFT, button height gains additional 4 pixels in aid of second one.
What I am doing wrong? Thank you for your valuable input!

I don't understand why you change compound. As for me you should set it once and forever. As for when you use None then it doesn't know how to calculate positions and it may use different rules for button size. So you should set compound once and never change it.

if you want to hide text then maybe set empty string - or rather string with single space because without space it doesn't know how to calculate text's height

@furas I didn't know that compound should be set once and never be changed. Changing compound setting to show/hide button's text seemed like the best and easiest option. I will go with your solution to change text string if needed. Thank you!

I checked code and it keeps size when I change text to single space - space is not visible but tkinter can calculate size. When I set empty text then it has problem with size. As for compound - I never saw anyone use it to hide/show text - and maybe authors of tkinter also didn't expect that someone will use it to show/hide text. Other idea: use two Buttons in one line, one with image, other with text, and later hide second button using grid_forget() - maybe it will work better.

Try setting padx=0 and pady=0 when creating the two buttons.

@furas Yeah, solution with compound set once to tk.LEFT and changing text value between space and target phrase works but there is problem with centering image when real one (not dummy) is used. The workaround is to change compound between tk.CENTER and tk.LEFT when text=" " and text="example" is used respectively

@acw1668 your solution is the perfect match to my case. Just added pady=0  and it works as intended. No more height changes :)
Anyway, thank both of you!
